# QML FileDialog issue

Tags: qt, qml, filedialog

I am trying to use the `FileDialog` component in QML.

I have done exactly the same code that is in the Qt documentation at the link http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html and it does not show the dialog and returns the error: `QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename`. I tried to write a simple code to test it and the return was the same error. My code is below.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

Window {
    visible: true

    width: 360
    height: 640

    maximumHeight: 640
    minimumHeight: 640

    maximumWidth: 360
    minimumWidth: 360

    title: "Acessar Galeria Test"

    Rectangle {
        id: principal

        anchors.fill: parent

        FileDialog {
            id: fileDialog

            title: "Please choose a file"

            folder: shortcuts.home

            visible: true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: code you posted is working fine for me. file dialog did show as expected. have you tried changing folder to a string something like `folder: "/home/user/Documents"`?

Comment: Just a quick note: FileDialog's visible property is false by default, so no need to set it false explicitly. A "better" way to show it is simply to call yourFileDialog.open(), e.g., in this case in Component.onCompleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

`FileDialog` `visible property` cannot be true while the component is not complete. So the code must be like below:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

Window {
    visible: true

    width: 360
    height: 640

    maximumHeight: 640
    minimumHeight: 640

    maximumWidth: 360
    minimumWidth: 360

    title: "Acessar Galeria Test"

    Rectangle {
        id: principal

        anchors.fill: parent

        FileDialog {
            id: fileDialog

            title: "Please choose a file"

            folder: shortcuts.home

            visible: false
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        fileDialog.visible = true;
    }
}
```